# one problem about distributed training when i pretrain the BART

Tags: linux, deep-learning, pytorch, bert-language-model

I only used less than 7,000 pieces of data to pretrain the bart and use eight 3080 graphics cards,I should have enough memory,however,it report out of memory.Here is some code

```
GPUS_PER_NODE=8
MASTER_ADDR=localhost
MASTER_PORT=6000
NNODES=1
NODE_RANK=0
WORLD_SIZE=$(($GPUS_PER_NODE*$NNODES))

DISTRIBUTED_ARGS="--nproc_per_node $GPUS_PER_NODE --nnodes $NNODES --node_rank $NODE_RANK --master_addr $MASTER_ADDR --master_port $MASTER_PORT"

python -m torch.distributed.launch $DISTRIBUTED_ARGS \
        pretrain_bart.py \
       --num-layers 12 \
       --hidden-size 1024 \
       --num-attention-heads 16 \
       --micro-batch-size 1 \
       --global-batch-size 8 \
```

As you can see, my batchsize has been set to very small，next is error report

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 42.00 MiB (GPU 2; 9.78 GiB total capacity; 7.63 GiB already allocated; 4.56 MiB free; 7.66 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
```

This error occurs 8 times, once per GPU，I always feel like I'm still training with one GPU instead of eight together, so how do I solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

The information you provided seems insufficient to address the issue of CUDA out of memory. For example, have you set up CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES correctly (although it seems to be set correctly)? To confirm if you have used eight GPUs for training, you can try using `nvidia-smi` or `nvidia-htop` to see if the GPU usage during the training process occurs simultaneously.